# BI Publisher 12.2.1.3.0 Failed to XML Error

Tags: bi-publisher

When I click the View under the Data tab in DataModel I get an "Failed to XML" error. So I can not view and save the sample data.

Here is output of error;
[image]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to press "View Engine Log" to see what went wrong?

Comment: Yes, there is no any error in that xml file. Meanwhile, If I click the export button than I get xml file without any error. I can see the datas.

Comment: If the data model is not too complicated, can you give us the select statements? I bet one of those is causing your problem. You might be able to narrow it down yourself by hard-coding the values till you find the one causing the problem. Then from there you can find the row with the issue.

Comment: I don't use the sql, I created the model by using analysis. For testing purpose I created a simple analysis that has a column such as date and still get same error.